# Unrecognized error number: 8192: trim(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated

Tags: php, openldap, ubuntu-22.04

[image: error]

New to the field can find specific answer in the web hope you can help me with this. I didn't write the code I just follow a documentation on how to install openldap on php8.1 ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is an incompatibility between php 8.1 and phpldapadmin 1.2.6.3.  It looks like they fixed this in 1.2.6.4 , but there isn't an updated package from Ubuntu at the moment.

Comment: yeah PHP devs have gone insane not allowing to pass empty (null) values to `trim()` making another C from PHP, now waiting for `malloc()` to kill that language

Comment: Please keep in mind that StackOverflow is a site for programming-related issues. If you are facing any problem with existing software (where you didn't write any relevant code on your own), please file a bug report with their maintainers

Answer (score 3):

This particular bug has been raised by the community [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/phpldapadmin/+bug/1992366) and has been fixed starting from ubuntu 23

For ubuntu 22.04 users:
There is no actual fix version available on official repositories, you need to download the package from ubuntu archive and install it manually. follow the steps below:

1. download the phpldapmyadmin 1.2.6.3-0.3

```
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/phpldapadmin/phpldapadmin_1.2.6.3-0.3_all.deb
```

2. install it :

```
dpkg -i phpldapadmin_1.2.6.3-0.3_all.deb
```

3. fix/install dependencies

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP 8.1 no longer supports passing `null` values to `trim`, prior to 8.1 those values would be turned into an empty string internally, with 8.1 they will no longer be changed.

If you have access to the code you should check if the value is null before being placed into trim or default the value to an empty string. You would need to fix those areas lsited in that error output manually.